# How do I get inotify-like event notifications from an NFS server?

Tags: nfs, inotify

AFAIK, the Linux implementation of NFS doesn't support inotify-like event notification from the server-side -- is there a workaround, patch, or alternative solution that can produce the same data?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to use inotify on an nfs client to detect when files are modified on the server (possibly by other clients?)

Comment: @Dave Cheney: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I reported a feature request [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53161)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this mail](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/226162), running an inotify watcher on the server exporting the filesystem should catch when clients write to the filesystem.

Really, I'd recommend trying it. I find that it's usually best to give things a shot oneself, even if success seems unlikely (as long as there is no harm in doing so, of course).

Comment: +1. It may not work in all situations, but this is exactly the idea that occured to me when I read the question.

Perhaps you could add some sort of queuing system like RabbitMQ so that clients can pick up notification messages remotely.

Answer (score 0):

FAM used to have this feature way back when. I don't know if it has been/can be ported to use inotify as a backend, though...